# SyntaxError with single line while loop in timeit python module

Tags: python, while-loop, timeit

I am trying to execute a timing test for while loop in python. 
However, I am getting a syntax error from `timeit.timeit`. Below is the setup for working code on for loops:

```py
import timeit

iterations = 100000; n = 100
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: [i for i in range(n)], number = iterations)
print("With range: ",t)
```

This works without issue.

However, when I try the following on a while loop, I get a SyntaxError pointing to the 'e' in while.

```py
iterations = 100000; n = 100; i = 0;
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: while i < n: i+=1, number = iterations)
print("With while: :",t)
```

However, I know this one line while loop works.

```py
n = 3; i = 0;
while i < n: print(i); i+=1
# Output: 
# 0
# 1
# 2
```

So, I wondering if someone knows that issue here. Thanks.

Comment: The body of `lambda` can't contain any **instructions** (including `while`, `for`, `if` etc. - it is just a single **expression**.

Comment: "while" is a statement. Statements are not allowed in a lambda. Use a regular function if you need "while".